# How can I concatenate a column into existing column of list in pandas that is not None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to concatenate a column to a list of columns. It concatenates all the data in the column. However, I don't want to concatenate the column that is not NaN or None.

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick'], 'Grade':[[20, 21],[ 19, 18]],'Science':['23',None]} 
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Grade']=df['Grade'].append(df['Science'],ignore_index=True)
df.apply(lambda row: row['Grade'].append(row['Science']), axis=1)
```

Result I get is :

```
    Name    Grade   Science
0   Tom     [20, 21, 23]    23
1   nick    [19, 18, None]  None
```

What I want :

```
    Name    Grade   Science
0   Tom     [20, 21, 23]    23
1   nick    [19, 18]    None
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for `None` to append:

```
df['Grade'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Grade'] + [row['Science'] ] 
                                      if row['Science'] is not None else row['Grade'], 
                       axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    [20, 21, 23]
1        [19, 18]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a comprehension

```
df.assign(Grade=[g if s is None else [*g, s] for g, s in zip(df.Grade, df.Science)])

   Name         Grade Science
0   Tom  [20, 21, 23]      23
1  nick      [19, 18]    None
```